# Replace dictionary items in a file

Tags: python, dictionary, substitution

So, I'm trying to replace some strings in a file, which has many of them. I tried:

```
html_char = {
        '"' : '&quot',
        "'" : "&apos;",
        '&' : '&amp;',
...
}

def parser():
        f = open("file.txt", "w+")
        line = f.read()
        for key, val in html_char.items():
                line = line.replace(key,val)
        print("Writing succeded!")
        f.close()

parser()
```

But I'm not being successful. It prints the "Writing succeeded!", although the file remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:
First ( 2 files)

```
html_char = {
        '"' : '&quot',
        "'" : "&apos;",
        '&' : '&amp;',
}

def parser():
        f = open("file.txt", "r")
        f2 = open("file2.txt","w")
        line = f.read()
        for key, val in html_char.items():
            line = line.replace(key,val)
        f2.write(line)
        f.close()
        print("Writing succeded!")


parser()
```

Second: (1 file)

```
html_char = {
        '"' : '&quot',
        "'" : "&apos;",
        '&' : '&amp;',
}

def parser():
        f = open("file.txt", "r")
        line = f.read()
        for key, val in html_char.items():
            line = line.replace(key,val)
        print("Writing succeded!")
        f.close()
        f = open("file.txt", "w")

        f.write(line)
        f.close()


parser()
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!!! Do you know why it is not writing in the same file, though?

Comment: I edited, because the flag. You have to read first the file, next you have to open the file in write mode and write

Comment: Why not use Python's `with` context manager? It's safer because it ensures that files get closed.

Answer (score 0):

This code will change the file in place:

```
def parser(filename):
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
        lines = []
        for line in f:
            lines.append(''.join([html_char.get(i, i) for i in line]))
        f.seek(0)
        f.writelines(lines)
        f.truncate()
```